# MySQL remove duplicates with OR operator

Tags: mysql, operators, distinct

I have 3 tables (`a`, `b`, `c`) where table `c` is a "tag" table. Table `a` is like a product table and table `b` is the normalized table between table `a` and `c`.

In words: Entries in table `a` can have multiple keys of table `c` (Product xyz has tags tag_1, tag_2, tag_3, and so on).

**Table a**

[image: Table a]

**Table c**

[image]

**Table b**

[image]

As you can see id 3 from table `a` has 2 tags assigned.

What I want to do is to get a result of all rows that have either tag 1 OR tag 2. The task is actually pretty easy

```
SELECT *
  FROM a INNER JOIN b ON (a.id = b.a_id)
         INNER JOIN c ON (c.id = b.c_id)
 WHERE (tag_name = 'First' OR tag_name = 'Second');
```

[image]

However, I want to remove the duplicate of the row with a_id = 3 (name = a_3).

A `DISTINCT` does obivously not work in this case.

How can I do this?